# Swift: Can't use mutating method in Protocol Extension

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols

I have a 4 view controllers that need to use a different image based on the user screen width.  I am trying to keep the code DRY and use protocol extension.

Below is my protocol:

```
import UIKit

enum ScreenWidths: CGFloat {
        case iPhone455s = 320.0
        case iPhone6 = 375.0
        case iPhone6Plus = 414.0
}

protocol ScreenSizeProtocolExt {
    mutating func setupBG() -> String    
}


extension ScreenSizeProtocolExt {
    mutating func setupBG() -> String {
        let imageName: String
        let userScreenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

        switch userScreenWidth {
        case ScreenSizeWidth.iPhone455s.rawValue:
            imageName = "imageA"
        case ScreenSizeWidth.iPhone6.rawValue:
            imageName = "imageB"
        case ScreenSizeWidth.iPhone6Plus.rawValue:
            imageName = "imageC"
        default:
            imageName = "imageAll"
        }

        return imageName
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use it:

```
extension myViewController: ScreenSizeProtocolExt {

let imageToUse = setupBG()
// Here is get an error: 'Use of instance member 'setupBG' on type 'inout Self'; did you mean to use a value of type 'inout self' instead?
let image = UIImage(named: imageToUse)
imageView.image = image

}
```

How can I use a protocol extension to detect the screen width and provide me with the right `imageName` to use.

Comment: You can't just have floating code in an extension... you need to put it in a method

Comment: I am trying to reuse the code.  If I put the code where I am adapting the protocol, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: inside the `extension myViewController: ScreenSizeProtocolExt` I am trying to create an image based on the right string that's sent back by the protocol extension and assign it to a local imageView variable.

Comment: So when do you want to do this? You need to tell the compiler when to execute code by putting it in a method. `viewDidLoad` maybe?

Comment: so what should I put in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Put `let imageToUse = setupBG() ... imageView.image = image` in `viewDidLoad`, either in the extension, or if you already have `viewDidLoad` implemented in the original class, put the code in there and conform the class directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
extension myViewController: ScreenSizeProtocolExt {    
let imageToUse = setupBG()
// Here is get an error: 'Use of instance member 'setupBG' on type 'inout Self'; did you mean to use a value of type 'inout self' instead?
let image = UIImage(named: imageToUse)
imageView.image = image    
}
```

isn't legal.  The main thing is that extensions can't add new stored properties -- so you can't do:

```
let imageToUse = setupBG()
```

In an extension.

Also, this line:

```
imageView.image = image
```

Is illegal outside of a `func`.

As to what you need here, this all seems like overkill.  Why extend this to the viewControllers with protocols?  You have a function that returns an imageName -- that could be anywhere (just a free func, not in a class).

Then, in the viewControllers, just set the image view's image to the name returned by this function.

Extensions are a way to give more interface to a class -- you can't make the class call the methods automatically just via extension.